# Why is my delete where statement not working?

Tags: javascript, sql, sqlite

I am trying to delete a user from table USERS. Unfortunately, I keep getting sent to onSqlError. I can't figure out why. When I alert the request it gives me the correct name for the getTheId variable. Not too familiar with sql so maybe I have written something incorrectly. Any pointers appreciated.

```
// DELETE RECORD
function deleteRecord(getTheId){
    deleteUser.onclick = (function () {//deleteUser is an element generated for each user when a button is clicked
        var sqlStr2 = 'DELETE FROM USERS WHERE username = '+getTheId+'';
        alert("SQL: " + sqlStr2); //This gives me the statement above with the correct name of the user clicked.
        if (db){
            console.log("db is there");//this logs
            db.transaction(function(tx) {  
                   tx.executeSql(sqlStr2);
            }, onSqlError, onSqlSuccess); //THEN I GET SENT TO ERROR
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: The username needs to be in quotes.

Comment: Note that the [Web SQL standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/webdatabase/) has been abandoned for 4+ years. Though, implementations do allow for using placeholders -- `WHERE username = ?` -- so parameters can be provided without as much risk of [SQL Injection](https://xkcd.com/327/) -- `tx.executeSQL(sqlStr2, [getTheId]);`

Comment: Thanks Barmar. As you didn't leave answer, I have marked your comment as useful. Majid L's solution works.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan. I will try implement the solution in the format you suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var sqlStr2 = "DELETE FROM USERS WHERE username = '"+getTheId+"'";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a ';' to the end of your statement, although without an error message it's hard to tell.